# Validate if path(znode) exists in zookeeper using zookeeper-shell.sh

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I need some help to validate if the znode(path) exists in zookeeper using zookeeper-shell.sh

Example: `bin/zookeeper-shell.sh zk:9091 ls /brokers/idss` Here `/brokers/idss` does not exists in the zookeeper it throws message 
 `Node does not exist:`

I want to use this in my if condition and proceed with logic.

Any help would be really appreciated?

Comment: is this intended to work in a script, or by some programming language?

Answer (score 0):

From ZooKeeper 3.4.7 and upwards, there is support in zkCli for command processing.
So you could issue a command like the following to check if a znode exists:

```
zkCli.sh -server host:port get /test/path
```

This is a bash command and its return value can be used in an if condition.
In case of an error (KeeperError exception, relevant Error codes can be found [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/apidocs/zookeeper-server/index.html)), a non zero value will be return. If the node exists and you can have read access to it, 0 is returned.